Non-binding ♦ close vote
Sometimes a post has crossed the line so patently that a moderator can simply close it.
Sometimes, however, a post might be walking near the line, and it is at least "not obvious" if it should be closed or not.
In this latter case, can a moderator decide to cast a non-definitive closing vote, i.e. a vote which simply counts as 1 instead of directly closing the post?

Why not just press skip instead?

@NickODell in case you mildly want to close a post, without using your full ♦-power to close it, but casting a simple vote like any other user.

Ah. I misunderstood.

Heh, I remember this feature was requested back in the happy Stack Exchange 1.0 days ... too bad it's still not implemented.

I wish. Unfortunately we either have to close/delete/whatever outright or abstain from voting. I tend to abstain unless it's really obvious or the question already has 3+ votes on it.

It's like all we have is a machine gun and we encounter a rude child.
